# How to convert rows to columns using pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have table with data like this

```
A|B|C|D|E|
----------
100|ABC|OL|Decmber|100
100|ABC|OL|January|200
100|ABC|OL|February|290
100|DEF|OL|Decmber|260
100|DEF|OL|January|300
100|DEF|OL|February|360
200|ABC|OL|December|500
200|ABC|OL|January|600
200|ABC|OL|February|550
200|DEF|OL|December|570
200|DEF|OL|January|600
200|DEF|OL|February|680
----------
```

I want the output should be

```
A|B|C|December|January|February
100|ABC|OL|100|290|300
100|DEF|OL|200|260|360
200|ABC|OL|500|550|600
200|DEF|OL|600|570|680
```

As the values are dynamic so i have below query:-

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @cols = STUFF(
             (
                 SELECT Distinct
                        ','+QUOTENAME(c.[D])
                 FROM #rolling  c FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
             ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');
SET @query = 'SELECT [A],[B],[C],'+@cols+'from (SELECT [A] ,[B],[C],

[D] as [Month],  


  [E] as [amount]
FROM #rolling
)x pivot (min(amount) for Month in ('+@cols+'))p';
EXECUTE (@query);
```

But i am getting the output something like this.

```
A|B|C|ABC|DEF|
100|December|OL|100|200
100|January|OL|290|260
100|February|OL|300|360
200|December|OL|500|600
200|January|OL|550|570
200|February|OL|600|680
```

As the Month names in that table are dynamic that's why i use this.
But the output i am getting like that.
Please help me how can i achieve the result as i mentioned earlier.

Comment: Please don't Spam Tag RDBMS. Edit and add the specific RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or Oracle? The answer won't be the same...

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - as you use STUFF() function so it seems your dbms is SQL SERVER

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=04e2ee603623d81abf5e7c51446df2ff)**

```
declare @sql varchar(max)='',@col_list varchar(8000)=''

set @col_list = (select distinct quotename([D])+',' from #rolling
for xml path(''))

set @col_list = left (@col_list,len(@col_list)-1)

set @sql = 'select A,B,C,'+@col_list+' from
#rolling
pivot (max([E]) for [D] in ('+@col_list+'))pv'

exec(@sql)
```

OUTPUT:

```
    A   B   C   December    February    January
   100  ABC OL    100        290         200
   100  DEF OL    260        360         300
   200  ABC OL    500        550         600
   200  DEF OL    570        680         600
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
Sorry for the wrong table structure i have given the new one now could you please check it once

Comment: @roll where is your table structure

Comment: @roll, I've considered your first table - have you checked the demo

Comment: Yes,But I am not getting the result as expected.The values are inserted to the data base as i edited now

Comment: @roll - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=04e2ee603623d81abf5e7c51446df2ff - check here I've edited my table according to your data

Comment: When i use this  set @col_list = (select distinct quotename([D])+',' from t1
for xml path('')) Distinct it is diaplying month names in Alphabatical order.
like Decmber,February and March but i need them in order what i actually have